# Exercise on Complicated Processing of a Large CSV Customer Data File (MATLAB or C++)

Tags: c++, matlab, csv, file-io

I have data in a CSV file formatted as follows:

[image]

The data continues until:

[image]

Because of the addition and removal of customers over time and their relative ranking within each date per the original source file's rules, there is no guarantee that the customer id will consistently appear in the same order or in all dates.  However, there are no duplicates within a given date.

Note that there are several more numerical attributes to the right of eod_cust_bal_usd.

The goal is to implement the following:

1. Remove weekend and (US) holiday dates.
2. Group customers into groups according to the following rule.  Each customer has a numerical attribute; call it V.  If V=0 for all dates, then the customer goes into Group 0; call it C0.  If max(V) falls into the [0,1/3) percentile (where the max is taken over all dates), then the customer goes into group 1; call it C1.  And so on for [1/3,2/3) <-> C2 and [2/3,1] <-> C3.
3. Sum all of the numerical attributes of the customers for each date within their group.

The final output CSV should look like:

[image]

down to

[image]

where now eod_cus_bal_usd (and all other attributes not shown) is renamed to eod_cohort_bal_usd and is the sum of all the eod_cus_bal_usd corresponding to that cohort (group) according to #3 above.

---

At first I thought this would be a pretty straight-forward task, but it has been quite a painful exercise to implement in C++.  It is acceptable to use MatLab if this makes it easier to handle/process the data.  Any ideas on implementation would be helpful (pseudo code is fine).

Some things to keep in mind:

- cust_id should be considered a string since not all id's are numerical
- The dates run from 12/1/2013 to 5/30/2014; there are some 500,000 entries in total, so memory allocation at run-time could be an issue.
- There are some 17 numerical attributes associated with each customer, and since they must be summed after the grouping with other customer's attributes in the same group, whatever grouping method that is used must carry the attributes as well, not just the customer id.

**EDIT - CURRENT PROGRESS**

This is my ultra crude first attempt at an implementation so far.  It loads the data into memory using the STL map container.  I've tested it and it reproduces the correct results and does the file I/O properly (although the I think there is a precision issue with stod in converting std::string into a double since the numerical values are off somewhat).  I haven't tested this on the file with around half a million rows; I just tested it on a subset of three dates (~7,000 rows).  Even with this, it takes

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

const int N = 3; // 181

struct cust_data {
 cust_data() {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   bal_date[i] = "";
   cust_id[i] = "";
   for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    txn_data[i][j] = 0;
  }
 }
  string bal_date[N]; // date balance is recorded
 string cust_id[N]; // customer id
 double txn_data[16][N]; // 16 ordered transaction values
};

int main(void) {

 // STEP 1
 // Load customer aggregated file into memory
 ifstream iFile("test.csv");
 map<string, cust_data>  dataMap;
 string csvLine;
 csvLine = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  long iFilePos = 0;
  getline(iFile, csvLine);
  istringstream ss(csvLine);
  string tempDate1;
  string tempDate2;
  string tempId;
  getline(ss, tempDate1, ',');
  tempDate2 = tempDate1;
  while (tempDate1 == tempDate2) {
   getline(ss, tempId, ',');
   dataMap[tempId].bal_date[i] = tempDate2;
   dataMap[tempId].cust_id[i] = tempId;
   for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    string tempField;
    getline(ss, tempField, ',');
    dataMap[tempId].txn_data[i][j] = stod(tempField);
   }
   iFilePos = iFile.tellg();
   getline(iFile, csvLine);
   ss.clear();
   ss.str(csvLine);
   getline(ss, tempDate2, ',');
  }
  iFile.seekg(iFilePos, ios::beg);
 }
 iFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered loading / using a Database ???. A database should be able to do this fairly easily be Ms-Access, Oracle, DB2 etc

Comment: See my edit above for what I've done so far.  @Bruce I haven't considered this, but I'm personally even less familiar with DB tools than programming tools such as C++.